# How to write unit tests with gem `memory_profiler` usage?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, memory, memory-leaks

For example, we have class implementation:

```
class Memory
  def call
   2 * 2
  end
end
```

we can get report by memory_profiler usage:

```
require 'memory_profiler'
MemoryProfiler.report{ Memory.new.call  }.pretty_print
```

How to implement the unit test for this which became failed when we have an increase of memory or memory leak in addition changes into `Memory#call`?

For example, if we going to change `Memory#call` in this way:

```
- 2 * 2
+ loop { 2 * 2 }
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd start with "why?" before "how?". Why do you need such a strange test?

Comment: to check allocated memory exceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should place it as unit tests, cause testing is a bit different environment it should not be aware of time cost or memory cost for your code, it should not verify metrics, it is job for other tools.

For your case I would advice to write some module, where you can assert that allocated memory is ok for you, for example you can do something

```rb
module MyMemsizeNotifier
  extend self
  ALLOWED_MEMSIZE = 0..4640

  # Or you can receive block, lambdas, procs
  # I will leave it for you implementation
  def call(klass) 
    report = MemoryProfiler.report
      klass.new.call
    end

    exceeds_limit?(report.total_allocated_memsize)
    report
  end

  def exceeds_limit?(total_usage)
    return if ALLOWED_MEMSIZE.include?(total_usage)

    # notify in rollbar, write a log to stdout or to file or any other way to notify
  end
end

## Usage

class MyController
  def index
    ...
    MyMemsizeNotifier.call(Memory)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for, the one more question about it: how you get this number `4640` ?

Comment: @AlexeyStrizhak
I just run simple example in my console, just to play with gem on my own. you can change it to the one you need, for example wrap your code inside `memory_profiler` block and pass code, and inspecting `report` result object you will get this `total_allocated_memsize` for me it was `4640`